# Why do six asp.net dev server ports open when I debug?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis

Recently,  when I go to debug, SIX dev server ports are started on my system.

Can someone explain to me what has happened and/or what to do to shut it off?

Thanks!

[image: Six ports open everytime I debug]

These six STAY there no matter how many times I debug.  I do not get more than six and they are not phantom servers that disappear when moused over.

Comment: If you were to debug again, will it create an additional six?

Comment: *"These six STAY there no matter how many times I debug."* That's normal behavior.  The servers continue to run even after you've detached Visual Studio's debugger from them.  In fact, if you don't need to debug and just want to look at an update, simply re-building will allow you to re-load the page without attaching the Visual Studio debugger, since the server is still running.  As for why there are six (or seven?) of them... How many web applications are in your solution?

Comment: 6... besides the web site that I am trying to debug.  However, these were there before this started.  Did somebody maybe change a behavior in the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have several Web Applications or Websites in your current solution

Since you could be exposing Web Services in your web projects, Visual Studio simply *loads everything*

Personally I find this behavior annoying, if you guys know a setting to configure this, it would be appreciate it